# How does Delphi manage memory allocated for Objects created as parameters?

Tags: delphi, memory-management

The title might seem a little confusing, but the heart of my question is: What happens to the memory allocated in both of the following scenarios?

## Scenario 1:

```pascal
var
 FHTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse;

...

FHTTPResponse := HTTPClient.Post(RequestURL, TStringStream.Create(APostParams.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8));
```

The `TStringStream` object is created in the parameters list of a function (in this case, `THTTPClient.Post`). What happens with the memory allocated for it, as I created it but (afaik) I'm not able to free it.

## Scenario 2:

```pascal
  ExampleClass = class
    private
      FName, FValue: string;
    public
      constructor Create(AName, AValue: string);

      function AsStringList: TStringList;
  end;

implementation

function ExampleClass.AsStringList: TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.Add(FValue);
  Result.Add(FName);
end;

constructor ExampleClass.Create(AName, AValue: string);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
  FName := AName;
end;
```

When the user calls `ExampleClass.AsStringList`, my understanding is that I'm not returning a reference to an object, like I would if I had a field `FAsStringList`, but the *object itself*.

In this scenario, I'd be passing the responsibility of freeing the `TStringList` object (which feels just wrong). Does anything else happen underneath this return? Is there a better approach to return the data as different structures, that doesn't imply giving the user the responsibility of freeing the object without them even knowing they have to do so?

**TL;DR** Is there a better (or a correct) approach to returning data representation as different object types without transferring memory management responsibilities to the user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Object-type variables/parameters/returns/etc in Delphi are references to objects, not actual objects themselves. Objects reside only in dynamic memory and cannot be passed around by value, only by reference.

Any call to `Create()` an object type *must* have a matching call to `Free()` (or `Destroy()`) to free the object from memory, otherwise the object is leaked.

So, in Scenario 1, the `TStringStream` is leaked if `HTTPClient.Post()` does not take ownership of it and free it. And in Scenario 2, the `TStringList` is leaked if the caller of `AsStringList()` does not take ownership of the returned list and free it.

In Scenario 1, let's assume `Post()` does not take ownership of the stream (seems like a reasonable assumption). The caller should maintain ownership of the stream and free it after `Post()` returns, eg:

```pascal
var
  FHTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse;
  Strm: TStringStream;

...

Strm := TStringStream.Create(APostParams.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  FHTTPResponse := HTTPClient.Post(RequestURL, Strm);
finally
  Strm.Free;
end;
```

In Scenario 2, the caller must take ownership and free the returned `TStringList`, eg:

```
var
  instance: ExampleClass;
  list: TStringList;
...
list := instance.AsStringList;
try
  ... 
finally
  list.Free;
end;
```

If you don't want to transfer ownership of the `TStringList` to the caller, then `ExampleClass` must maintain ownership of it internally, eg:

```
type
  ExampleClass = class
  private
    FName, FValue: string;
    FList: TStringList;
  public
    constructor Create(AName, AValue: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function AsStringList: TStringList;
  end;

implementation

constructor ExampleClass.Create(AName, AValue: string);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
  FName := AName;
  FList := nil;
end;

destructor ExampleClass.Destroy;
begin
  FList.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function ExampleClass.AsStringList: TStringList;
begin
  if FList = nil then
    FList := TStringList.Create
  else
    FList.Clear;
  FList.Add(FValue);
  FList.Add(FName);
  Result := FList;
end;
```

Otherwise, the caller would need to create its own list and pass it to the class to fill in, eg:

```
type
  ExampleClass = class
  private
    ...
  public
    ...
    procedure AsStringList(AList: TStrings);
  end;

implementation

procedure ExampleClass.AsStringList(AList: TStrings);
begin
  AList.Add(FValue);
  AList.Add(FName);
end;
```

```
var
  instance: ExampleClass;
  list: TStringList;
...
list := TStringList.Create;
try
  ...
  instance.AsStringList(list);
  ...
finally
  list.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Just to be sure, the connection between two scenarios is that: If the library coder wants to manage it themselves they must store it **internally**, In first scneario by creating a variable to hold the TStringStream object then free it before returning and in second scenario by creating a field internally and returning that field?

Comment: @ArthurAraujo as I stated in my answer: "*Any call to Create() an object type must have a matching call to Free() (or Destroy()) to free the object*" - period. WHO frees the object is a matter of code design, but it needs to be done regardless. So do make sure you pay attention to who owns which object when writing your code.